# How can I update Text with dynamic data in customComponent of drawer navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using react navigation, and I want to update some text whenever user change the data.

```
const AppDrawNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: {screen: HomeStackNavigator},
  Rewards: {screen: RewardsStackNavigator},
  Flavours: {screen: FlavoursTabNavigatorClass}
}, {
  contentComponent: CustomeDrawer
})

const CustomeDrawer = (props) => {
  return(
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}
      forceInset={{ top: 'always', horizontal: 'never' }}>
        <View style={{height: 150, backgroundColor:'white'}}>
          <Text style={{color: 'black', fontSize: 18, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>customDrawer</Text>
           <Text> {/* Here i want to display updated text */} </Text> 
        </View>
        <ScrollView>
          <DrawerNavigatorItems {...props} />
        </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
```

Comment: What do you change exactly?

Comment: are you using Redux ?

Comment: I have TextInput in another component and whatever user inputs that should be displayed in CustomDrawer.

Comment: Can it be done using AsyncStorage..?

Comment: Anyone having the solution for this.?

Comment: You can use useSelector with redux, or something like that with other state management tools

Comment: Can you share some link which is related to updating text in Drawer navigation? I am using AsyncStorage.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. I don't know whether this is correct approach or not.? But this seems to working for me.

```
const CustomeDrawer = (props) => {
  return(
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}
      forceInset={{ top: 'always', horizontal: 'never' }}>
        <View style={{height: 150, backgroundColor:'white'}}>
          <Text style={{color: 'black', fontSize: 18, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>My customeDrawer Text</Text>
        </View>
        <ScrollView>
          **<CustomDrawer />**
          <DrawerNavigatorItems {...props}/>
        </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

{/* Here we will define the main screen of drawer navigator */}
const AppDrawNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: {screen: HomeStackNavigator},
  Rewards: {screen: RewardsStackNavigator},
  Flavours: {screen: FlavoursTabNavigatorClass}
}, {
  contentComponent: CustomeDrawer
})

In my custom Drawer component:

import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, SafeAreaView, AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';

export default class CustomDrawer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: ''
        }
    }
    componentDidMount = () =>  {
        AsyncStorage.getItem('name').then((name) => this.setState({name}))
    }

    render() {

        return (

            <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1, width: '100%', alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}> 
            <Text style={{width:'100%'}}>
                {this.state.name}
            </Text>
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }
}
```